# LINQ to join a lists of list-items into one list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list like this:

```
public class list 
{ 
    public IList<list2> list {get;set;}
}
```

And a `list2` like this:

```
public class list2 
{
    public string something {get;set;}
}
```

The result I want is this:

```
var listWithAll = new List<list2>();

foreach (var item in list) 
{
    foreach (var item2 in item.list) 
    {
        listWithAll.Add(item2);
    }
}
```

Is there a short LINQ handler I can use do to this?
Something like this:

```
list.Select(x => x.list);
```

But this doesn't work obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) for this purpose:

```
var listWithAll = list.SelectMany(x => x.list).ToList();
```

The `SelectMany`:

> Projects each element of a sequence to an `IEnumerable<T>` and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.

Answer (score 4):

Use `SelectMany` method of LINQ

```
var newlist = list.SelectMany(x => x.list).ToList();
```

> `SelectMany` flattens queries that return lists of lists.

For further details refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx)